# Infinite loop in getter/setter c#

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        something s = new something();
        s.DoIt(10);
        Console.Write(s.testCount);
    }
}

class something
{
    public int testCount
    {
        get { return testCount; }
        set { testCount = value + 13; }
    }

    public void DoIt(int val)
    {
        testCount = val;
    }
}
```

Is what I have, because I was wanting to test and play around with the getters/setters stuff for C#. However, I get a StackOverFlowException was unhandled at "set { testCount = value + 13}". And I can't step through it, as I get a "The debugger cannot continue running the process. Process was terminated" message from Visual Studio. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Today I've learned that I've done a pretty stupid derp. Given the multitudes of instant responses. Now I know better.

Comment: You're accessing the same propery inside the setter. You probably need to have a private variable which you use to access your through your public property. (Not flaming but this code got me shivering)

Comment: Ahh. I'm not too used to how properties work, and I just need to throw a crap shot together to try to understand something.

Comment: To explain the infinite loop, what @ToonCasteele means is that since you call the set method of `testCount` in *its own setter*, the actual set method calls itself infinitely.

Comment: @Fender - in some ways, the existence of [auto properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) makes this an easy error to make. When one _had_ to use a backing field for simple properties, well... you had a backing field.

Comment: Yeah.. Didn't think calling it in the setter would cause it to continue calling itself. Makes sense now, though.

Comment: That's also why the debugger is shitting itself when you try to break there

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have an infinite recursion, as you are referring to the property *in* the property.

You should use a backing field for this:

```
private int testCount;
public int TestCount
{
    get { return testCount; }
    set { testCount = value + 13; }
}
```

Note the property name `TestCount` (which also conforms to C# naming standard), as opposed to the field name `testCount` (lowercase `t`).

Answer (score 5):

You should declare a variable to back the property:

```
class something
{
    private int _testCount;
    public int testCount
    {
        get { return _testCount; }
        set { _testCount = value + 13; }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a circular reference in your property's getter. Try this:

```
class Something
{
    private int _testCount;
    public int TestCount
    {
        get { return _testCount; }
        set { _testCount = value; }
    }

    public void DoIt(int val)
    {
        _testCount = val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
public int testCount
{
    get { return testCount; }
```

it returns itself, which causes it to execute itself.

Instead of return the own property in itself, store the intended value in another (preferably protected or private) variable. Then manipulate that variable both in the setter and in the getter.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        something s = new something();
        s.DoIt(10);
        Console.Write(s.testCount);
    }
}

class something
{
    private int _testCount;

    public int testCount
    {
        // you are calling the property within the property which would be why you have a stack overflow.
        get { return _testCount; }
        set { _testCount = value + 13; }
    }

    public void DoIt(int val)
    {
        testCount = val;
    }
}
```