# Infinite loop in get method of a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a viewModel that has a ienumerable of selectitemlist for a drop box but in the get method I run into an infinite loop what should I do?

```
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TargetList
    {
        get
        {
            return TargetList;
        }
        private set
        {
            TargetList = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "Android", Text = "Android" },
                                                    new SelectListItem { Value= "WebGL", Text="WebGL" },
                                                    new SelectListItem { Value= "Windows", Text="Windows" },
                                                    new SelectListItem { Value= "IOS", Text="IOS" }};
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite loop in getter/setter c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694098/infinite-loop-in-getter-setter-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your get is calling itselft. You need to set up a backing field.

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _targetList

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TargetList
{
    get
    {
        return _targetList;
    }
    private set
    {
        _targetList = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "Android", Text = "Android" },
                                                new SelectListItem { Value= "WebGL", Text="WebGL" },
                                                new SelectListItem { Value= "Windows", Text="Windows" },
                                                new SelectListItem { Value= "IOS", Text="IOS" }};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a very strange setter because it doesn't use any value that you pass to it. You seem to have confused a setter method with an initialisation. Try this

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TargetList{ get; } 
                   = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "Android", Text = "Android" },
                                                new SelectListItem { Value= "WebGL", Text="WebGL" },
                                                new SelectListItem { Value= "Windows", Text="Windows" },
                                                new SelectListItem { Value= "IOS", Text="IOS" }};
```

No need for the thing to have a setter, unless you intend to actually set it to a different value from outside your class, which wouldn't work with your original setter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need body of getter or setter here.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.TargetList = new List<SelectListItem> 
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Android", Text = "Android" },
            new SelectListItem { Value= "WebGL", Text="WebGL" },
            new SelectListItem { Value= "Windows", Text="Windows" },
            new SelectListItem { Value= "IOS", Text="IOS" }
         }
     }
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TargetList
     {  get ; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having an infinite loop is that your getter is calling itself recursively with not termination condition. If you wish to initialize your property with some default values and also allow calling code to change it, you can use an auto-implement property like so...

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TargetList { get; set; } =
    new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Value="Android",Text="Android"},
        new SelectListItem() { Value= "WebGL", Text="WebGL" },
        new SelectListItem() { Value= "Windows", Text="Windows" },
        new SelectListItem() { Value= "IOS", Text="IOS" }
    };
```

In this way, you have your default items and it can still be set to a different list at runtime if you wish. If you don't want the list changed, then you can do without the `set;` portion of the property.